# C#, how do I make a clock work with added hours?

Tags: c#, time, clock, timespan, hour

Using Visual Studio 2008 (C#) I have to make a working clock (digital) with the current time zone hour, and a few more with different time zones, like new york, etc.

inside the form I put 2 labels (for the clocks) and a timer, inside the timer I put this code:

```
 timer1.Interval = 1000;

        label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;


        TimeSpan myTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0);
        DateTime myDateTime8 = myDateTime + myTimeSpan;
        label2.Text = ("" + myDateTime8);
```

the part with the timespan does add 2 hours to the clock, however, instead of just the actually clock I also get the date on it's left, like for example:

"17-05-2011 22:38:00"

I need to know how can I add/subtract hours and only show the clock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding a timespan, simply call the AddHours method:

```
myDateTime.AddHours(2).ToLongTimeString();
```

Comment: Fantastic!
So simple yet worked perfectly, thank you very much, for the fast and accurate response ;)

Answer (score 1):

myDateTime.ToShortTimeString() will return you only time

or as `Tejs` mentioned you can use `ToLongTimeString()` that  I guess more suits your requirement.

For adding or subtracting hours you can use `dateTime.AddHours(even hours in negative)` or for subtracting you can also use `dateTime.Subtract(time to subtract)`

Answer (score 0):

Using the .ToString() method of the timespan method allows you to output the date in any format you want. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. For your time zone needs, use an approach similar to the one suggested in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546098.aspx). Notably:

   1. Use [`ConvertTimeToUtc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimetoutc.aspx) to get UTC time before performing any arithmetics.
   2. Perform required arithmetics.
   3. Convert back to local time using [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382835.aspx).
2. To get just the time part of a `DateTime`, use [`DateTime.ToShortTimeString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring.aspx). Note that this is culture-aware, so if you want a fixed format, consider using [`DateTime.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) to specify a format.